# Honor - Is there a way to know how far I am from leveling down/up?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new Honor system is here!

[image]

It functions by level, but is there a way to know at what percentage you are through that level? Like LP, but for the Honor system?

Just to know your progress, and how close you are from leveling up your honor.

Comment: afaik, no. Also I've been looking on reddit and the league forums and haven't heard mention of anyone being honor 3 yet, so I think it's a very very very slow process. They're unlikely to share this information as it will lead to people exploiting the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest preseason patch, Riot has [updated the Honor system again](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/honor), this time adding three checkpoints to each level of Honor. Now you can earn a few more guaranteed rewards over the course of the season.

Unfortunately, though the progression is a little more segmented (which makes seeing how quickly you're leveling up a little easier), there's still no "real time" way to see how fast you're progressing.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is absolutely no way to tell what level you are in honor. What we do know is that everyone on your team honoring someone will increase your honor level a little bit more, and getting honored will increase your honor level somewhat faster. I am still level 2, like every single player I know, and I don't think anyone will level up for a couple of weeks. Riot has said that leveling up in honor is supposed to be a month long or season long process, not a couple of days or weeks.

Comment: This is correct. It makes sense that the process of leveling up takes an entire season, since the only way to lose honor points is by being punished for toxicity, something that doesn't happen in sporadic cases; you really have to work at being a jerk to get punished.

Comment: The Riot honor FAQ has more details for anyone interested: https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008474148-Honor-FAQ

Answer (score 1):

You will be only informed when you got uprank/derank. I've got lvl 3 honor 2 weeks ago, if i had to say how much honor i received it would be ~50-70.
**Factors that matters:**
- If whole team honor someone, everyone receive a little honor boost.
- Votes from premade give not so much honor as from other players.
- Getting chat restriction/ban reduce your honor

https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008474148
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Honor

Comment: Maybe provide a link to a more accurate source describing how honor level works for further clarification. Riot games actually wrote some articles about how and why their honor system is what it is now.